# Suggestions for dealing with the sharp corner of a storm drain

Tags: concrete, metal

The (city-owned) storm drain outside my house has a corner that protrudes about half an inch from the line of the sidewalk. It's sharp enough to puncture a tire; I've lost a few to it over the years, as have my neighbors. Complaining to the city has had no effect.

[image]

So I'm thinking of doing something about it myself. My thought is to fill the space out with some concrete. Any suggestions on the exact steps to take so that it'll bond properly and not flake off if a tire hits it while parking?

(The alternative, I suppose, would be to grind down the corner, but that sounds hazardous.)

Comment: I would grind it late at night when no one is looking!

Comment: This would be considered 'Destruction of Public Property' in most places, and may be punishable by fines and/or jail time.

Comment: That's why you do it at night :P  I don't know where you live, but I wouldn't want to live there if you'd go to jail for that!  Considering my city charges $400 plus length for things like a curb cut, the fine might even be the cheap way to go!

Comment: @Steven In the US, jail time is an option for breaking just about any law ever written.  I think it's written that way so if you're a huge jerk to the police they can throw you in jail.

Comment: take some strong pliers and bend it down a bit (a piece of wood and a hammer would also do)

Comment: If you hit the curb while parking, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @ChrisF: _tire_ is the American spelling.

Comment: @BMitch - oops. Sorry - I thought I knew all the common variants.

Answer (score 3):

[Sledgehammer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sledgehammer)

[image]

Pound that corner down.

When nobody is looking. :)

Comment: Or stop parking with your tires that close to the curb.  That's too close anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

Send the city a bill for the tire, take them to small claims court if necessary, they will fix the problem.

Comment: We got rid of a tree in a similar manner.